# How to make a new column based on difference of max values by index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take the following multi-indexed dataframe:

```
index_1   index_2   cum_value
0         2020-01      100.00
0         2020-02       50.00 
0         2020-03      -50.00
0         2020-04      150.00
0         2020-05      200.00    
1         2020-01       25.00
1         2020-02       50.00
1         2020-03     -100.00
1         2020-04       50.00
1         2020-05      200.00
```

I need to create a `new_col` to compute the difference of last `cum_value` for each `index_1`, if this `cum_value` has increased on that month considering the past max value inside that `index_1`, on previous months.

The result should be like this:

```
index_1   index_2   cum_value   new_col
0         2020-01      100.00    100.00 --> first positive value on index_1 [0]
0         2020-02       50.00      0.00
0         2020-03      -50.00      0.00
0         2020-04      150.00     50.00 --> (150 - 100)
0         2020-05      200.00     50.00 --> (200 - 150)
1         2020-01       25.00     25.00 --> first positive value on index_1 [1]
1         2020-02       50.00     25.00 --> (50 - 25)
1         2020-03     -100.00      0.00
1         2020-04       50.00      0.00
1         2020-05      200.00    150.00 --> (200 - 50)
```

The first row with positive value on `new_col` must show this value. I don't need negative max values.

This is the rationale to calculate marginal values to pay some taxes.

Comment: Are the positive values always in the increasing order in column `cum_value`?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma no. They can be positive but lower from previous positives.

Comment: So consider if the value in the column `cum_value` corresponding to index `0   2020-04 ` is `50` in place of `150`, What will the output in that case?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma zero because 50 is not greater than the previous max, that is 100. Ie. it is not the new max. I only want to subtract the last 2 max values to see the residual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code

```
c = df.groupby(level=0)['cum_value'].cummax()
m = df['cum_value'].ge(c) & df['cum_value'].ge(0)
df['new_col'] = df.loc[m, 'cum_value'].groupby(level=0).diff()
df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].fillna(df['cum_value']).mask(~m, 0)
```

#### Explanations

Let us `group` the dataframe on `level=0` i.e. `index_1` and transform the column `cum_value` using `cummax` to calculate the **cumulative maximum value** per `level=0` group:

```
>>> c

index_1  index_2
0        2020-01    100.0
         2020-02    100.0
         2020-03    100.0
         2020-04    150.0
         2020-05    200.0
1        2020-01     25.0
         2020-02     50.0
         2020-03     50.0
         2020-04     50.0
         2020-05    200.0
Name: cum_value, dtype: float64
```

Now, compare the `cum_value` column with the above calculated cumulative max values to create a boolean mask. Note we are considering only the positive values in `cum_value`. The idea behind this boolean mask is that if the current month value is greater than or equal to the maximum value from the previous months, then the ouput of this mask will be `True` otherwise `False`.

```
>>> m

index_1  index_2
0        2020-01     True
         2020-02    False
         2020-03    False
         2020-04     True
         2020-05     True
1        2020-01     True
         2020-02     True
         2020-03    False
         2020-04     True
         2020-05     True
Name: cum_value, dtype: bool
```

As we are only interested in the values from the `cum_value` column that satisfies the above condition, we can use boolean masking to filter such values.

```
>>> df.loc[m, 'cum_value']

index_1  index_2
0        2020-01    100.0
         2020-04    150.0
         2020-05    200.0
1        2020-01     25.0
         2020-02     50.0
         2020-04     50.0
         2020-05    200.0
Name: cum_value, dtype: float64
```

Now `group` the above filtered values on `level=0` i.e `index_1` and use `diff` on the `cum_value` column to calculate the differences between the current value and previous max value:

```
>>> df.loc[m, 'cum_value'].groupby(level=0).diff()

index_1  index_2
0        2020-01      NaN
         2020-04     50.0
         2020-05     50.0
1        2020-01      NaN
         2020-02     25.0
         2020-04      0.0
         2020-05    150.0
Name: cum_value, dtype: float64
```

Finally, fill the `NaN` values in the newly created `new_col` and mask the values with `0` which do not satisfy the condition `m`:

```
>>> df
                 cum_value  new_col
index_1 index_2                    
0       2020-01      100.0    100.0
        2020-02       50.0      0.0
        2020-03      -50.0      0.0
        2020-04      150.0     50.0
        2020-05      200.0     50.0
1       2020-01       25.0     25.0
        2020-02       50.0     25.0
        2020-03     -100.0      0.0
        2020-04       50.0      0.0
        2020-05      200.0    150.0
```

Comment: Great solution!! It worked for the dataframe fragment. My only question: if the first max values are negative, I need to ignore those maxs and `new_col` must show zero. Fixing this the solution is perfect.

Comment: @DanielArges Very good observation..I will update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, Very nicely explained, thanks for sharing sir cheers.